# Whats the difference between Page Builder Plugins and Theme Builder Softwares?

Tags: plugins, themes

As everyone might be aware that there are many wordpress website builders in the market, Can anyone explain me whats the real difference between Theme Builders and Page Builders? I looked up in google but couldn't find the answer to it.

Comment: downvoted as it is not even remotely related to actual development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between a theme and a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5513/difference-between-a-theme-and-a-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

So basically a 'page builder' is a drag-and-drop system for pages and posts. This way you can easily define where you want your content. Page builders are theme agnostic. (See for example Visual Composer)

A 'theme builder' is usually the theme options. Header/footer colours, sidebars, font's, etc. With a 'theme builder' you can edit the look of your website and sometimes choose different layout styles aswell. See for example the WordPress Customizer under appearance in the WP-Admin.

I hope this makes it a bit more clear. A theme builder usually comes with a theme. While a page builder is for creating the particular layout of pages. (While some themes offer a page builder. A lot are theme agnostic.)

Comment: customizer is a theme builder? i don't think so search for theme builder you will same result as page builder.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani, In that case, there are no differences. But for the sake of this question; A ***THEME*** builder is more likely to be the options panel of your theme. And a ***PAGE*** builder for the layout of your pages. I suppose we should keep those things separate. Whether a page builder is being called a theme builder is irrelevant since that would extend this question very broadly and undefinable. Then again, if you think you have a better explanation, just add a Answer to this post.

Answer (score 2):

Both seems same, same question came in my mind before & i've also searched and found almost same results on both queries **WordPress Theme Builder** & **WordPress Page Builder**

What they actually are:

Page Builders help you create your website pages like creating a page layout, put content with styling, images sections etc, simply page builders like [Visual Composer](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431?ref=thememotif) gives you drag & drop layout facility with ready made template option as well to create a website page (like Home, About Us, Contact or whatever), aim is to create a desired layout for the page.

**Theme General Options**

With regards to changing theme **General Settings** like typography, skins, header, footer, blog layout etc. Most themes have builders for changing general settings (stated above), some are integrated in `Appearence > Customize` and some themes have their own different setting panel for changing design's general options, but these panels are theme specific while page builders help you create a layout in any theme.

I hope that's clear enough.